# Is there a way to detect that an application has been force stopped on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, action, broadcastreceiver

There is an intent action for a broadcast receiver to detect if an application has been uninstalled.

The intent action is: `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED`.

I would like to know if a similar intent action broadcast receiver exists to detect if an application has been force closed.

Answer (score 0):

No, this operation is done through a Binder and there is no intent accompanied